# Check checkbox wthin a specific class grouped div

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below has two sets of checkboxes, each set split by a div class `EachCategorySet`.

When I click a `parent` checkbox it should check all its `child1` `child2` checkboxes, but it should stay within its group as defined by class `EachCategorySet`.

But with the current code, if I click on the `A1` checkbox, it checks all same class checkboxes without respecting its group div class `EachCategorySet`. How can I limit this to check only within div class `EachCategorySet` and not go to the next set of divs?

Here is [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bs6ktfL8/2/)

Html:

```
<div class="EachCategorySet">
   <div class="accordion-heading">
      <input type="checkbox" class="parent" name="parent"> A1
   </div>
   <input type="checkbox" class="child1" name="child1"> A2
   <input type="checkbox" class="child2" name="child2"> A3
</div>
<br/>
<div class="EachCategorySet">
   <div class="accordion-heading">
      <input type="checkbox" class="parent" name="parent"> B1
   </div>
   <input type="checkbox" class="child1" name="child1"> B2
   <input type="checkbox" class="child2" name="child2"> B3
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 //parent class checkbox action
 $(".parent").change(function () {
   if (this.checked) {
     $('.child1').prop("checked", this.checked);
            $('.child2').prop("checked", this.checked);
   }
 });
 //child1 checkbox action
  $(".child1").change(function () {
   if (this.checked) {
            $('.child2').prop("checked", this.checked);
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

Note that by using `this.checked` you know if the parent checkbox is checked or not, so you can use that value to set the child checkboxes to the same value -- so you only need the one function.

```js
//parent class checkbox action
 $(".parent").change(function() {
      $(this).parent().find('.child1').prop("checked", this.checked);
      $(this).parent().find('.child2').prop("checked", this.checked);
 });
  $(".child1").change(function() {
      $(this).parent().find('.child2').prop("checked", this.checked);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="EachCategorySet">
<input type="checkbox" class="parent" name="parent">
A1
<input type="checkbox" class="child1" name="child1">
A2
<input type="checkbox" class="child2" name="child2">
A3
</div>
<br/>
<div class="EachCategorySet">
<input type="checkbox" class="parent" name="parent">
B1
<input type="checkbox" class="child1" name="child1">
B2
<input type="checkbox" class="child2" name="child2">
B3
</div>
```

References:

Moving up/down in the DOM tree, or from one element to the next, is called DOM Traversal.  Here is more information about that subject.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing.asp

Comment: Question updated. Actually the parent checkbox lives in another div `class=accordion-heading`. I was forgot to add this

Answer (score 1):

If those child checkboxes are confined within the same div, you can use the [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function.

```js
 $(this).siblings('.child1').prop("checked", this.checked);
```

You can also use [attribute selection](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to generalize, like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/06kbhnr5/